# How to send a <select> in a form using the enter key without a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title states, Is it possible? Or do I really need a submit button to submit it?

I tried something but unfortunately it didn't work for me, or maybe there's an error in the code.

Here is the code that I've tried:

```
document.getElementById("select_id").addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
    };
});
```

Here's the html:

```
<form id="form_id" action="processor.php" method="POST">
    <select id="select_id" name="chosenProduct">
        <option value="product_a">Product A</option>
        <option value="product_b">Product B</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [Markup is missing..]

Comment: Sorry for that,I posted using mobile.I'll try that JSFiddle

Comment: add keypress listener to a select element? Or send a `submit` in a form using the enter key in a `text` field?

Comment: you can use on change event

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for the edit

Comment: @amow overall I want to send a select element inside a form using the enter key. I just copied that code somewhere just to test if it works for me

Comment: How could you confirm the element `select_id` is listening to `keypress` event when you press a key ?

Comment: @Chandra if I used onchange,won't that fire a script the moment I changed the select's value? If so, then I can't use it. I'm hoping for a script that will send a form with a select element by pressing the enter key

Comment: @passion I don't really know, that code is just based in results of my search in this problem. Based from my understanding of that code, the select is waiting for a keypress that has a code of 13 before sending the form_id,so I thought it would work

Comment: @CarlJanBinalla  Your code will work when the select element is onfocus .

Comment: @passion I do focus in the select,but everytime I press Enter, the Select just drops down the list and nothing else

Comment: @CarlJanBinalla  any errors logged ? post code plz

Comment: if you want to run the script on enter key press then try using onkeypress event, this works on enter

Comment: put javascript after html

Comment: Thanks for everyone who commented and answered,cheers to all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello try something this

add `event.preventDefault();` before `document.getElementById("form_id").submit();`I think you missed this.
IF still doesn't work then

use below codes  using keypress function

```
  /* without button*/

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#select_id").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#form_id").submit();
  }
  });
 });
```

/* with button key press event*/

```
  $("#select_id").keyup(function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 13){
    $("#id_of_button").click();
   }
   });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Every time I chose something in the drop down then pressed the Enter key,the list just drops down without doing anything. I tried the preventDefault then the first example.

Comment: Hey! the first example was not completed before i have edited that now please let me know that whether it works or not.

Comment: Just tried it,still has the same problem,the list drops down when pressing the Enter key

Comment: Silly me,i haven't changed the id of the select,but its name,its working now, thank you very much

Comment: I really wish most answers didn't assume you have a certain javascript library available.

Answer (score -1):

use onkeypress for submitting form on enter

```
<form id="form_id" action="" method="POST">
<select id="select_id" name="chosenProduct" onkeypress="document.getElementById('form_id').submit()">
    <option value="product_a">Product A</option>
    <option value="product_b">Product B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Won't that fire the script the moment I changed the select's value? If so,then I can't use it

Comment: i have updated code..may be it would do the same you want

Comment: It works,but all key press are being captured not just the Enter,thank you for answering.